# Could we bond hydrogen to the edges of covalent network structures like diamond?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, surface-chemistry

I know that diamond is just carbon atoms structured in a way that differs from graphite and charcoal. The carbon atoms on the edges do not have full valence shells. Would it be possible to attach hydrogen atoms (or other elements) to complete these shells? And if this is possible, would it change the properties of the diamond?

Comment: It would be impossible **not** to attach anything. You just can't have dangling bonds with nothing on them. When you see a diamond, it is already covered with something: maybe $\ce{-H}$, maybe $\ce{-OH}$. And no, this does not affect the properties (most of them).

Comment: [What is the edge of a diamond like?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7115)

Comment: What covers the surface is very important to device properties in diamond (and other semiconductors as well). It impacts carrier recombination and surface-induced fields.